# Query to return 'n' character after like query search

Tags: sql, database, oracle, oracle12c

Looking out for a SQL query (Oracle system) wherein:

Data is: `<some 100 lines>https://xyc.com/display/abc/action?=123123132 <some more lines>`

Over here the 123123123 will be dynamic number

So I require a query to return the search condition with next n dynamic data
select Body from abc where data like '%https://xyc.com/display/abc/action?=%'

Custom output should be:

```
Data
https://xyc.com/display/abc/action?=123143534
https://xyc.com/display/abc/action?=123443454
https://xyc.com/display/abc/action?=776465454
```

Answer (score 1):

If each record has only one URL which you want to extract, then you should be able to use `REGEXP_SUBSTR`:

```
SELECT REGEXP_SUBSTR (col, '(http\S*)')
FROM yourTable
```

This assumes that the URLs either have whitespace after them, or are the last thing occurring in the column.

Comment: URL would be having either " OR > , something else too. That can't be sure what exactly it would be.